# How can I edit my code to concurrency using in Go?

Tags: go, concurrency

I have a function **getIPSetInfo** that makes HTTP requests as many times as there are elements in  `IpsetInfo` array.
How can I redesign my function to use multithreading?
I need all those queries in loop to be done in parallel.

```
type IpsetInfo struct {
    OrgRef               ObjDesc  `json:"orgRef"`
    EdgeGatewayRef       ObjDesc  `json:"edgeGatewayRef"`
    OwnerRef             ObjDesc  `json:"ownerRef"`
    NetworkProviderScope string   `json:"networkProviderScope"`
    Status               string   `json:"status"`
    Id                   string   `json:"id"`
    Name                 string   `json:"name"`
    Description          string   `json:"description"`
    Type                 string   `json:"type"`
    IpAddresses          []string `json:"ipaddresses"`
}

func getIPSetInfo(ipsetIds []string) []IpsetInfo {
    var result []IpsetInfo
    for i := range ipsetIds {
        url := "https://api-cloud-platform.com/cloudapi/1.0.0/firewallGroups/" + ipsetIds[i]
        _, body := httpGet(url, map[string]string{
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
        })
        var x IpsetInfo
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &x)
        result = append(result, x)
    }
    return result
} 

func main() {
    ipsetIds := getIPSetIDs()
    IPSets := getIPSetInfo(ipsetIds)

    // Below terraform manifest will be created from template 
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("ipsets.template")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    f, err := os.Create("result.tf")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("create file: ", err)
        return
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(f, IPSets)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("execute: ", err)
        return
    }
    f.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this could help

```
func getIPSetInfo(ipsetIds []string) []IpsetInfo {
    mu := &sync.Mutex{}
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    
    var result []IpsetInfo
    
    call := func(val string){
        defer wg.Done()
        
        url := "https://api-cloud-platform.com/cloudapi/1.0.0/firewallGroups/" + val
        _, body := httpGet(url, map[string]string{
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
        })
        var x IpsetInfo
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &x)
        
        mu.Lock()
        defer mu.Unlock()
        
        result = append(result, x)
    }
    
    for _, val := range ipsetIds {
        wg.Add(1)
        go call(val)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    return result
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of using mutex in this context? You do not attach it to any object

Comment: The error is occurred: undeclared name `call`

Comment: ahh sorry updated the code

Comment: the code `append` is not thread-safe and the array is shared across the go-routines that's why we use mutex synchronisation primitive to overcome the problem with `append`

Comment: Why you've created mutex in the way " &sync.Mutex{}" ? Can we just create it like `var mu sync.Mutex`? What the difference in this case?

Comment: you can do `var mu sync.Mutex` nothing special. I was writing without any editor so forgot to change that part

Comment: @NeenadIngole I understand that you want to make `result` slice thread safe. To make it work you need to declare another structure and include `result` and `mu sync.Mutex` as its components. Like it is described [here](https://gobyexample.com/mutexes)

Comment: yeah you got it exactly right now :D, hope you learned new stuff ;)

Comment: YES!!! I can now see your point :)